# Spark SQL: String comparison not working for varchar or char types

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL inside a Scala application via spark-submit to query data from CSV-style fi0les.

I use the following query to create and populate the table `part`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE part (
    p_partkey bigint,
    p_name varchar(55),
    p_mfgr char(25),
    p_brand char(10),
    p_type varchar(25),
    p_size int,
    p_container char(10),
    p_retailprice double,
    p_comment varchar(23)
) 
USING CSV
LOCATION 'part.tbl'
OPTIONS(delimiter "|");
```

Which works fine and I can query data, e.g., by using `SELECT * FROM part;`.

However, if I want to filter the data on the `p_brand` column with the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM part WHERE p_brand = 'Brand#12';
```

It does not return any results, even though there are clearly multiple rows with `Brand#12` in the dataset. Note that it does *not* throw any exceptions, it just returns an empty result set.

But, if I use `string` datatype instead of `char(10)` for `p_brand` in the table schema, the above query correctly returns the desired rows.
Note that `varchar(10)` does also not return any results. It really only works if I use `string` as the datatype for `p_brand`.

Does Spark SQL not support string comparisons for `char` or `varchar` strings? Is there any other way to do string comparisons in Spark SQL?

Thanks for any help.

System:

- Spark 3.3.2
- openjdk 17.0.6
- Scala 2.12.15
- Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: strings use normaly like and try TRIM

Comment: Spark pads shorter values of char type to length. Perhaps you can try filtering using `'Brand#12  '`?

Comment: In my case `varchar` and `string` returns result using `=`, but char not. Use `like` clause to get result for char type.